# Get git repository .git from remote into an existing working copy

Tags: git, github

I have a project that's managed via git and I deleted the .git folder.  Is it possible to grab only the .git only from the remote repository instead of cloning the entire repo again?

Comment: The .git is the whole repo...

Comment: I know hence "get git repo .git" - I want to get the repo again into an existing working copy without downloading the working copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clone to an empty directory, then move the .git to your existing working copy.

You can use `git clone -n` to avoid the checkout of the HEAD after the clone, but you'll have to move the .git anyway, because there doesn't seem to be a way to clone into a non-empty directory.

Comment: Should I do clone --bare so working copy is not downloaded?

Comment: The working copy is never downloaded. The server doesn't have any working copy. The repo is downloaded, then the HEAD is checked out from this repo, and the working copy is thus created based on what's in the downloaded repo. If you don't want to create the working copy, read my answer, and use `git clone -n`. Note that I didn't know anything about this `-n` option flag. All I had to do to find it is `git clone --help`, and read.